# The specific word must be somewhere between two substrings regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have a `regex` to find sentences that start with **Today** and end with **.** or **•** but somewhere between the first word (Today) and the last word (.\•) the word **the** must be in sentence.

```
description = 'Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April. Other sentence ...'
pattern = re.finditer("(Today).*?[\.•]", description, re.IGNORECASE)
for i in pattern:
    print(i.group(0))
# desired output: Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April.
```

But the code I wrote does not check for the word **the**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If neither the `.` and `•` are allowed, you can use 2 [negated character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^.•]` matching any character except the listed characters without using a capture group.

```
\bToday\b[^.•]*\bthe\b[^.•]*[.•]
```

- `\bToday\b` Match the word `Today` between word boundaries to prevent a partial match
- `[^.•]*` Match 0 or more times any char except `.` or `•`
- `\bthe\b` Match the word `the` between word boundaries
- `[^.•]*` Match 0 or more times any char except `.` or `•`
- `[.•]` Match either `.` or `•`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/82FDDg/1)

For example using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) to get a list of strings:

```
import re

description = 'Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April. Other sentence ...'
pattern = re.findall(r"\bToday\b[^.•]*\bthe\b[^.•]*[.•]", description, re.IGNORECASE)
for s in pattern:
    print(s)
```

Output

```
Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April.
```

Answer (score 0):

A classic approach would be to use the `re.match` function and adjust the regex to your needs. You could use some regex documentation like the one [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp) and adjust it for your needs.
use the `group()` method to access result, when there is no match None is returned.

Therefore your code could be something like:

```
import re

description = 'Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April. fds'
pattern = re.finditer("(^Today).*( the +).*(\.|•)", description, re.IGNORECASE)

for i in pattern:
    print(i.group(0))
```

Which prints 'Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April.'

When the word 'the' is omitted nothing is printed out.

Comment: As I wrote ` to find sentences` I want the sentence that starts `Today` and end with `.` and I do not want the rest of the string. I updated the question. Your answer also accepts things like `thee`.

Comment: Your question was not clear.
You want exactly the word "the"? add a space before and after it in the regex like i just edited my answer.

the ending symbol is NOT necessarily in the end? remove the `$` symbol.

Comment: There is a difference between the last word in the stream and the last sequence in the regex you are looking for.  anyhow the last element ( `dot` or `circle`) symbol you were looking for is not at the end of the stream, it's just has to be After the "the".

Comment: exactly the word "the"? yes, exactly. Your answer still is not what I want. for example the output of `Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April. fds.` must be `Today is a beautiful day in one of the last days of April.`